# Content script targeting iframes is not triggered on a particular website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

## Background

I am creating an extension which is supposed to execute the content script in every frame. The extension consists of two files:

**manifest.json**

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["<all_urls>"],

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "match_about_blank": true,
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }]
}
```

**content.js**

```js
console.log('content script loaded')
```

In brief, every time a frame starts to load its [contentDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument), the content script is loaded and then logs a message. In additon, if you manually insert a blank frame as follows, the content script will be triggered, too.

```js
var frame = document.createElement('iframe')
document.body.appendChild(frame)
```

## Question

I have tested it on several websites, e.g., https://www.google.com, and all things work as expected. **However**, I found that if I manually insert blank frames on https://www.twitch.tv by the method mentioned above, the content script won't be triggered for some reason. It seems that scripts from the website is able to intercept the operation and append the frame to the DOM in a unique way without triggering my content script.

I tried to trace the code, but still don't have a clue how it is possible for a normal script to do that. Can anyone help?

## My Platform

- OS: Windows 7
- Chrome: 76.0.3809.132

Comment: I've tested this and it seems to work (injecting the content script), maybe `console.log` has been overridden, you can check the contexts in dev tools, in the console tab https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/reference#context

Comment: I have tried putting `debugger` statement in the same place, and it is not triggered, either. Since `debugger` can not be overriden, so I an sure the content script is not executed.

Comment: @Titus, if you manually insert a blank frame on https://www.twitch.tv, the content script also logs the message?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it seems the content script is added (it appears in the **Console** tab in the contexts menu) but not run, I had this problems in other version of Chrome (content scripts not working in `<iframe>`s with no `src` or their `src` set to `javascript:`), it seems it is back.

Comment: What I am really confused is that the exactly same operation works on www.google.com, but not on www.twitch.tv.

Comment: The only possible explanation I see is that it's a bug in Chrome, probably https://crbug.com/996659